GitHub Actions: Conditionals on null Inputs
I'm creating a workflow which builds a multi-stage Docker image, and has a Stage as an input. As you likely know, workflows triggered non-manually (by pushes, PRs, or releases) do not set inputs. Thus, I'd like an automated trigger to just build all stages of the Dockerfile.
Inputs:
 - client
 - server
 - indexer
 - all

The workflow uses steps such as:
      - name: Build and Push Image - Server
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v6
        if: ${{ !inputs || inputs.Stage == 'all' || inputs.Stage == 'server' }}
        with:
          platforms: linux/arm64
          push: true
          file: Dockerfile
          target: server
          tags: ${{ env.SERVER_IMAGE_TAG }}

However, this doesn't work. On non-manual triggers, the step is skipped.

Can't you use inputs.Stage || 'all' for every instance where you access the stage?

Answer: Use if !inputs.Stage Or if ${{ !inputs.Stage || inputs.Stage == 'all' }} for multiple conditions. inputs.Stage == null also works.
!inputs or inputs == null is always false, and will cause the stage to be skipped.
Unfortunately, GitHub actions doesn't document this case.
But I was able to use the act tool to find the solution. I'll include an example Workflow and act invocation to test it.
Local CLI invocation: act release -W .github/workflows/test-input-null.yaml
## Testing behavior of GitHub Actions when inputs are null
# act release -W .github/workflows/test-input-null.yaml

name: Test Inputs being Null
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*'
  release:
    types: [published]
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      ENV:
        type: string
        description: Environment to deploy
        required: true
        default: dev
      Stage:
        type: choice
        description: Dockerfile Stage to Build + Push. Defaults to 'all'
        required: false
        options: ["client", "server", "indexer", "all"]
        default: all

permissions:
  contents: read
  id-token: write

jobs:
  null-inputs-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: # Sets Environment specific `vars.` and `secrets.`. Unfortunatatly its value cannot be read in job steps. Use `vars.APP_ENVIRONMENT` instead.
      # Create 'prod' images on all merges to main and releases. Otherwise, manual ENV input, or default to 'dev'
      name: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && 'prod' || github.event_name == 'release' && 'prod' || inputs.ENV || 'dev' }}
      url: ${{ vars.FRONTEND_URL }}

    steps:
      - name: Print if inputs are 'all' (A control, will be skipped on non-manual triggers)
        run: |
          echo "Stage: '${{ inputs.Stage }}'"
        if: ${{ inputs.Stage == 'all' }}

      - name: Print if !inputs.Stage or all (Works as expected)
        run: |
          echo "Stage (may be null, uses inputs.Stage == null): \"${{ inputs.Stage }}\""
        if: ${{ inputs.Stage == null || inputs.Stage == 'all' }}

      - name: Print if !inputs.Stage or all (Works as expected)
        run: |
          echo "Stage (may be null, uses !inputs.Stage): \"${{ inputs.Stage }}\""
        if: ${{ !inputs.Stage || inputs.Stage == 'all' }} 

      - name: Print if !inputs or all (Gets skipped on non-manual triggers)
        run: |
          echo "Stage (may be null, uses inputs == null): \"${{ inputs.Stage }}\""
        if: ${{ inputs == null || inputs.Stage == 'all' }}

      - name: Print if !inputs or all (Gets skipped on non-manual triggers)
        run: |
          echo "Stage (may be null uses !inputs): \"${{ inputs.Stage }}\""
        if: ${{ !inputs || inputs.Stage == 'all' }}


inputs context is an object. When a workflow is triggered by a push event, this object is still present but empty. You can see it by adding this step to your workflow:
- name: Show inputs context
  run: |
    echo '${{ toJson(inputs) }}'
    echo '${{ toJson(inputs.Stage) }}'

The output will be
{}
null

In other words, inputs is never null
If you want to test for an empty inputs object you can do this
if: toJson(inputs) == '{}'

However, it is easier to test for the absence of an input value:
if ${{ ! inputs.Stage }}

I can also recommend explicitly testing for the event which would make this easier to read:
if: github.event_name == 'push' || inputs.Stage == 'all' || inputs.Stage == 'server'

You do not need to use ${{ }} in this case because you do not have '!'

toJson() is useful for debugging. I'll have to use that in the future.
